# PySerial cannot send data from macOS

Tags: macos, bluetooth, pyserial, uart

I cannot send data to a Bluetooth module HC-05 via Bluetooth. My friend that also uses macOS cannot send data either.

```python
import serial
from time import sleep

AR = serial.Serial('/dev/cu.xxxx', 115200)

if not AR.isOpen():
    AR.open()

try:
    while True:
        print('2')
        AR.write(b'BBRR\n')
        sleep(0.5)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    AR.close()
```

I sent data through Bluetooth and monitored the data received using coolterm through USB port. When I run the code, it enters the loop as it continuously print 2 without error but no data is received in coolterm.
The port used are found using `serial.tools.list_ports.comports()`, `ls -l /dev.cu/*` and `ls -l /dev.tty/*`. Tried all available ports found but none works.
Also tried sending data though USB and monitor through Bluetooth port but still doesn't work.
Why is it not sending through?